# array flipping with pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

```
int* m = new int [d1*d2]; 


   ptr1 = m; 
    ptr2 = m + (d2*(d1-1));

     if ( *ptr1 != *ptr2){  
       temp = ptr2;     
       ptr2 = ptr1;     
       ptr1 = temp;
    }
ptr1 +=d2;
ptr2 -= d2;
```

In order to do

From

> 4 1
>
> 3 7
>
> 5 2

To

> 5 2
>
> 3 7
>
> 4 1

This is what i've came up with so far which is pretty much nothing.
I'm having problems with finding what kind of a loop would fit in.

Comment: why not declare an array of pointers and flip those?

Comment: It's been a while since I've done this, but shouldn't it be ptr1 = &m, ptr2 = &m + ((d2 * d1) - 1)? then you do += / -= (data type size * 2)?

Comment: You really should use `std::swap(*ptr1, *ptr2)`. That makes it far clearer what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just reverse the whole thing and then reverse each row:

```
row/col representation:
4 1 => 2 5 => 5 2
5 2    1 4    4 1

actual layout of m:
4 1 5 2 => 2 5 1 4 => 5 2 4 1
```

Comment: So first i take it's transpose.I guess i can do that.But then its comes up to same problem doesn't it just row instead of column ?

Comment: You've allocated a flat (1-dimensional) array, you can reverse that. Then you _interpret_ that array as 2-dimensional with something like `m[x + cols*y]`, so you can reverse each of those rows.

Comment: @user2362377: Flipping a row is essentially the same problem as flipping a column, except it is much faster because the stride is 1, you use cache better.  Still, if you think in terms of exchanging two rows, instead of flipping a column, you will have a simpler and faster answer yet.

Comment: I've menaged to reverse my array but still having problems with the 2nd part.Some code would be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

You need two loops, one for the rows that you want to flip, and then to flip each element on that row. So `int row` runs from 0 to 2, and `int column` runs from 0 to 1, when flipping your 3x2 matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Better ways have been described in the previous answers. So my answer will address why nothing changed in your output. You were swapping pointers not values. You want to do:

```
temp = *ptr2;     
*ptr2 = *ptr1;     
*ptr1 = temp;

--ptr2;
++ptr1;
```